# How to delete all characters comes after "-" in for all rows

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am working on notepad++. I have JSON format data like this

```
{
    "hcenter": "left",
    "vcenter": "middle",
    "value": 523,
    "products":"27-RJ" ,           
  },
  {
   "hcenter": "left",
   "vcenter": "middle",
   "value": 323,
   "products":"12-TF",                     
  },
```

from `products` value I want to remove all characters after `-` and need to remove `-` too. This is how I am trying to replace with empty `string` but not wokring

```
"products": "/-*"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"products":"[^-]+\K-[^"]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"products":"        # literally
[^-]+               # 1 or more non hyphen
\K                  # forget all we have seeb until this position
-                   # an hyphen
[^"]+               # 1 or more non quotes
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]